# Since multithreading applications in python looks very similiar to opencl / cuda - is it possible to port the application to GPU multithreading?

Tags: python, multithreading, cuda, opencl

If one takes a look at the following multithreading code, where a function `kernel` is defined, that will add a vector in parallel, one may see some similarites to CUDA / OpenCL kernel - such as:

1. You need a thread id  / kernel - id for addressing the vector
2. There is no return value, since you write to the memory provided
3. You need to allocate the memory of the output before hand

from threading import Thread

```
def kernel(i,A,B,C):
    """
        Does a vector addition 

        @param A output vector
        @param B input vector
        @param C input vector
    """   

    A[i] = B[i] + C[i]



vec_length = 1000

#Allocate memory
A = [None] * vec_length
B = [1] * vec_length
C = [2] * vec_length

processes = []
for i in range(0,vec_length):
    processes.append(Thread(target=kernel,args=[i,A,B,C]))
    processes[i].start()
for i in range(0,vec_length):
    processes[i].join()

print(A)
```

My question is, if there is an easy way to export the parallelism of the code to GPU. Of course not by writing the CUDA / OpenCL - but by either using a existing tool for this issue or to create such tool if it is possible.

Of course this may not work for advanced applications. I am aware of PyCuda - however this will result in rewriting the application.

Answer (score 1):

Is not as easy as it looks. GPU programming is very different from CPU, and there are many things that you can do in Python that you cannot do on a GPU. The most complicated one is the fact that python is an interpreted language, which requires a lot of dynamic memory allocation and function pointers. This is not supported on GPU devices, which means you cannot for example simply create an interpreter of python that runs on the GPU. Another problem is that you cannot create individual threads on the GPU, each function submitted to a GPU (a kernel) starts a bunch of threads together. This means the traditional loops you have in that code will not work (at least not efficiently), since you are spawning individual threads on each iteration.
This is not a problem only for Python, but for almost all programming languages, and in general using some accelerator always require code changes to match the differences in the execution model.
There is some research work looking into [offering high level interfaces to interpreted languages](http://conf.researchr.org/event/MoreVMs-2017/morevms-2017-papers-opencl-jit-compilation-for-dynamic-programming-languages), but still is far from a production stage.